# How to remove contents of string after a character

Tags: stata

I'm cleaning a variable - `last_name` - that for some names the middle name is included after a comma, while for most names the middle name is stored in the variable `middle_name`.

Here are some examples:

```
last_name
Smith, R
Anderson, Jay
Epps,William
McKinsey,F
```

This is my code:

```
split last_name, p(,)
replace last_name = substr(last_name, 1, length(last_name)-3) if ///
            length(last_name2)==3
```

I could put this through a forvalues loop and increase the length of the strings I'm dropping but this feels like a crude method. Is there a cleaner way to drop all of the values after the comma (or any other character)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the position of the (first) comma.

Subtract 1.

That gives the substring to be kept.

```
replace last_name = substr(last_name, 1, strpos(last_name, ",") - 1)
```

Generalize for any other character.

But this should be done only if there is such a character:

```
replace last_name = substr(last_name, 1, strpos(last_name, ",") - 1)  if strpos(last_name, ",")
```

However, don't lose information you may want later. It's better to create a new variable:

```
gen surname = substr(last_name, 1, strpos(last_name, ",") - 1) 
replace surname = last_name if missing(surname)
```